# Unable to update the state when button inside table cell clicked , React Ant Design

Tags: reactjs, antd

i would like to update state when the table cell clicks. But the event handleClickis not firing. if I declare the handleClick outside the class then the event call happening but state is not defined message is coming.

How to update state if we click on other cells, which are outside of the class.
Here is my code showing below

```js
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { Table, Icon, Switch, Radio, Form, Divider, Button, Modal } from 'antd';

import * as productActions from './../../redux/actions/productActions';

const handleClick = (product) => {
  debugger;
  
  //UNABLE TO UPDATE STATE HERE
  // this.setState({
  //   visibleDeletePopup: true
  // });
  alert(JSON.stringify(product));
}

const columns = [{
  title: 'Name',
  dataIndex: 'name',
  key: 'name',
  width: 150,
  render: text => <a href="javascript:;">{text}</a>,
}, {
  title: 'Full',
  dataIndex: "stockIn['full']",
  key: `stockIn['full'`,
  width: 70,
},
{
  title: 'Half',
  dataIndex: "stockIn['half']",
  key: `stockIn['half'`,
  width: 70,
},
{
  title: 'Quarter',
  dataIndex: "stockIn['quarter']",
  key: `stockIn['quarter'`,
  width: 70,
},
{
  title: '90',
  dataIndex: "stockIn['ninty']",
  key: `stockIn['ninty']`,
  width: 70,
}, {
  title: 'Category',
  dataIndex: 'category',
  key: 'category',
}, {
  title: 'Action',
  key: 'action',
  width: 360,
  render: (text, record) => (<span>
    <button href="javascript:;" onClick={() => handleClick(record)}>Edit-{record.name}</button>
    {/* <Divider type="vertical" />
    <a href="javascript:;">Delete</a>
    <Divider type="vertical" />
    <a href="javascript:;" className="ant-dropdown-link">
      More actions <Icon type="down" />
    </a> */}
  </span>
  ),
}];


const showHeader = true;
let footer = () => 0;
const scroll = { y: 300 };
const pagination = { position: 'bottom' };


class ProductsPage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onProductSave = this.onProductSave.bind(this);
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      bordered: true,
      loading: false,
      pagination,
      size: 'small',
      expandedRowRender,
      title: title,
      showHeader,
      footer,
      rowSelection: {},
      hasData: true,
    };

    //Popup and submit button
    this.state.buttonSubmitLoader = false;
    this.state.visibleDeletePopup = false;
  }


  handleClick = (product) => {
    //UPDATE STATE // how?
  }

  showModal = () => {
    this.setState({
      visibleDeletePopup: true,
    });
  }

  handleOk = () => {
    this.setState({ buttonSubmitLoader: true });
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({ buttonSubmitLoader: false, visibleDeletePopup: false });
    }, 3000);
  }

  handleCancel = () => {
    this.setState({ visibleDeletePopup: false });
  }


  render() {
    const state = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <Table {...this.state}
            columns={columns}
            dataSource={state.hasData ? this.props.products : null}
            footer={() => this.getFooterDetails(this.props.products)}
            pagination={{ pageSize: 5 }}
          />
        </div>
       
      </div>
    );
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const props = this.props;
    props.actions.loadProducts();
  }

  courseRow(item, index) {
    return <li key={index}>{item.name}</li>;
  }

  onProductSave(product) {

    this.props.actions.createProduct(product);
    this.setState({
      product: ""
    });
  }

  onChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      product: e.target.value
    });
  }

  getFooterDetails(products) {
    return <label class="text-success">Total Records Count is {products.length}</label>;
  }

}


function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
  //In state.products, product is coming from root reducer, if you change 
  //the name products to abhi_products , then here you need to call products:state.abhi_products 
  return {
    products: state.products
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    actions: bindActionCreators(productActions, dispatch)
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ProductsPage);
```

Answer (score 3):

setState will work only within the component. If you want to do setState in function declared and you want to do setState then you have to pass this context to the function.

The below would work inside the component

```
  handleClick = product => {
      this.setState({
         visibleDeletePopup: true
     });
  }
```

**Update:**

The entire component code can be corrected as follows

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { Table, Icon, Switch, Radio, Form, Divider, Button, Modal } from 'antd';

import * as productActions from './../../redux/actions/productActions';


let footer = () => 0;


class ProductsPage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      bordered: true,
      loading: false,
      pagination: { position: 'bottom' },
      size: 'small',
      expandedRowRender,
      title: title,
      showHeader: true,
      footer,
      rowSelection: {},
      hasData: true,
    };

     handleClick = product => {
        this.setState({
           visibleDeletePopup: true
       });
    }
    //Popup and submit button
    this.state.buttonSubmitLoader = false; // never mutate state like this instead use setState method
    this.state.visibleDeletePopup = false;
  }

  showModal = () => {
    this.setState({
      visibleDeletePopup: true,
    });
  }

  handleOk = () => {
    this.setState({ buttonSubmitLoader: true });
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({ buttonSubmitLoader: false, visibleDeletePopup: false });
    }, 3000);
  }

  handleCancel = () => {
    this.setState({ visibleDeletePopup: false });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const props = this.props;
    props.actions.loadProducts();
  }

  courseRow = (item, index) => {
    return <li key={index}>{item.name}</li>;
  }

  onProductSave = product => {
    this.props.actions.createProduct(product);
    this.setState({
      product: ""
    });
  }

  onChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      product: e.target.value
    });
  }

  getFooterDetails = products => {
    return <label class="text-success">Total Records Count is {products.length}</label>;
  }


  render() {
    const { hasData } = this.state;
    const { products } = this.props;
    const columns = [{
      title: 'Name',
      dataIndex: 'name',
      key: 'name',
      width: 150,
      render: text => <a href="javascript:;">{text}</a>,
    }, {
      title: 'Full',
      dataIndex: "stockIn['full']",
      key: `stockIn['full'`,
      width: 70,
    },
    {
      title: 'Half',
      dataIndex: "stockIn['half']",
      key: `stockIn['half'`,
      width: 70,
    },
    {
      title: 'Quarter',
      dataIndex: "stockIn['quarter']",
      key: `stockIn['quarter'`,
      width: 70,
    },
    {
      title: '90',
      dataIndex: "stockIn['ninty']",
      key: `stockIn['ninty']`,
      width: 70,
    }, {
      title: 'Category',
      dataIndex: 'category',
      key: 'category',
    }, {
      title: 'Action',
      key: 'action',
      width: 360,
      render: (text, record) => (<span>
        <button href="javascript:;" onClick={() => this.handleClick(record)}>Edit-{record.name}</button>
      </span>
      ),
    }];
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <Table {...this.state}
            columns={columns}
            dataSource={hasData ? products : null}
            footer={() => this.getFooterDetails(products)}
            pagination={{ pageSize: 5 }}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  //In state.products, product is coming from root reducer, if you change 
  //the name products to abhi_products , then here you need to call products:state.abhi_products 
  return {
    products: state.products
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    actions: bindActionCreators(productActions, dispatch)
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ProductsPage);
```

Comment: Can you give me example. The Column render is outside of the class, if I put handleclick() inside class. Its unable to locate the method. ( Can you show both html and js)

Comment: So , you are asking me to declare columns inside class itself, so that the handleClick method is accessible.

Comment: @Abhi yes that is how you need implement in react make sure everything you keeps it within the component. I made small correction in my answer. That would work now

Comment: Check and let me know

Comment: I am checking.The antd component is big (html, events) . Is that best practice to make my custom component and put the antd component inside or leave as it is (the file may grow bigger and bigger right)

Comment: Try to divide big html and events into individual components. Don’t write everything in single component. Please do upvote and accept If my answer resolves your issue

Comment: @Abhi Please upvote and accept the answer if it resolves the issue

Comment: Thanks for this. Key for me was NOT passing a property to the handleClick function: () => this.handleClick(record) rather than (record) => this.handleClick(record). Also, I didn't need to declare columns in the render function. It worked when inside the class definition.

Answer (score 2):

```
    enter code here

const getColumns = (handleClick) => { // Note here
  return [
   {
      title: 'Name',
  dataIndex: 'name',
  key: 'name',
  width: 150,
  render: text => <a href="javascript:;">{text}</a>,
}, {
  title: 'Full',
  dataIndex: "stockIn['full']",
  key: `stockIn['full'`,
  width: 70,
},
{
  title: 'Half',
  dataIndex: "stockIn['half']",
  key: `stockIn['half'`,
  width: 70,
},
{
  title: 'Quarter',
  dataIndex: "stockIn['quarter']",
  key: `stockIn['quarter'`,
  width: 70,
},
{
  title: '90',
  dataIndex: "stockIn['ninty']",
  key: `stockIn['ninty']`,
  width: 70,
}, {
  title: 'Category',
  dataIndex: 'category',
  key: 'category',
}, {
  title: 'Action',
  key: 'action',
  width: 360,
  render: (text, record) => (<span>
    <button href="javascript:;" onClick={() => handleClick(record)}>Edit-{record.name}</button>
    {/* <Divider type="vertical" />
    <a href="javascript:;">Delete</a>
    <Divider type="vertical" />
    <a href="javascript:;" className="ant-dropdown-link">
      More actions <Icon type="down" />
    </a> */}
  </span>
  ),
}]
}
```

Then inside your component

```
 <Table {...this.state}
    columns={getColumns(this.handleClick)} // and Here
    dataSource={state.hasData ? this.props.products : null}
    footer={() => this.getFooterDetails(this.props.products)}
    pagination={{ pageSize: 5 }}
   />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either declare the columns variable inside the class constructor like this:

```
this.columns = []
```

and the event will be (you need to bind handleClick ofcourse):

```
onClick={() => this.handleClick(record)}
```

OR you can pass declare the columns outside as you do and call the the event handler with the class context:

```
onClick={() => ProductsPage.prototype.handleClick(record)}
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: ProductsPage.prototype.handleClick is not a function

Answer (score 0):

you can use column tag

```
<Table pagination={false} dataSource={this.state.responsible}>
    <Column title="name" dataIndex="name" key="name" />
    <Column title="Category" dataIndex="email" key="Category" />

  <Column title="Actions" dataIndex="Actions" key="Actions"
 render={(text, element, index)=>{
   return (<div>
    <i className="fas fa-edit text-success m-1" style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
      onClick={() => this.handleClick()}
    ></i>
    <i className="fas fa-trash text-danger m-1" style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
      onClick={() => {this.Delete(element._id)
 
      }}
    ></i>

  </div>)
 }}
  />
      
      </Table>
```